# Get the cid for Google Analytics in PHP/Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I want to track the usage of an API. So I'm using Zend_Http_Client to send POST-parameters to Google Analytic's collector. The [Google developers-page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#commonhits) tells me, that I have to send a `cid` (Anonymous Client ID). But how can I send it via PHP when it is part of the `_ga-cookie`?

Am I supposed to create my own `cid`? Or am I just too dumb to understand the manual?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the parameters sent directly through the [Measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#commonhits) must be created by you.

> [Client ID](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#user)  / Cid 
>   This anonymously
>   identifies a particular user, device, or browser instance. For the
>   web, this is generally stored as a first-party cookie with a two-year
>   expiration. For mobile apps, this is randomly generated for each
>   particular instance of an application install. The value of this field
>   should be a random UUID (version 4) as described in
>   http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt

I normally use a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) for this. There appears to be a PHP-function that does this: [com_create_guid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php) or maybe [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

Anwsers:

1. Yes you are supposed to create your own cid.
2. No the measurement protocol is very hard to understand and in a lot of cases the documentation isn't clear.  This has nothing to do with your intelligence.

TIPs:

1. You can test your requests using [Validateing hits](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/validating-hits).
2. Tutorial on using the Measurment protocol to track quota: [Monitoring Quota usage for Google APIs](http://www.daimto.com/monitoring-quota-usage-for-google-apis/)

Comment: added a couple of tips for you.  Might make things a little easer to understand.

Comment: As com_create_guid is Windows-only - here's the equivalent: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: yup just added that :)